# Why is my Apache POI code not reading excel worksheet?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, apache-poi

Why is my Apache POI code not reading excel worksheet?

My Code:

```
public class ReadExcelFile {
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    Workbook book = new XSSFWorkbook(ReadExcelFile.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("C:\\Users\\Gi\\Desktop\\ExcelReader\\ExcelFramework\\src\\test\\java\\com\\ExcelFramework\\ExcelFramework\\data\\data.xlsx"));
    Sheet sheet = book.getSheet("Sheet1");
    Row row = sheet.getRow(1);
    Cell cel = row.getCell(1);

    System.err.println("Value: " + cel.getStringCellValue());
}
```

}

Seem to be getting the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.internal.ZipHelper.prepareToCheckHeader(ZipHelper.java:211)
    at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.internal.ZipHelper.openZipStream(ZipHelper.java:228)
    at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.ZipPackage.<init>(ZipPackage.java:97)
    at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.OPCPackage.open(OPCPackage.java:342)
    at org.apache.poi.util.PackageHelper.open(PackageHelper.java:37)
    at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook.<init>(XSSFWorkbook.java:285)
    at com.ExcelFramework.ExcelFramework.ReadExcelFile.main(ReadExcelFile.java:11)
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Is your getResourceAsStream call really returning a stream? Usually you don't specify DOS-like paths there, but instead address relatively from your set classpaths, i.e. within the Jars or the classpath folders.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can try as below Using FileInputStream :

```
    Workbook book = new XSSFWorkbook(new FileInputStream("C:\\Users\\Gi\\Desktop\\ExcelReader\\ExcelFramework\\src\\test\\java\\com\\ExcelFramework\\ExcelFramework\\data\\data.xlsx"));
    Sheet sheet = book.getSheet("Sheet1");
    Row row = sheet.getRow(1);
    Cell cel = row.getCell(1);

    System.err.println("Value: " + cel.getStringCellValue());
```

Answer (score 0):

Please refer section **4. Apache POI library – Reading an Excel file** in  example https://www.mkyong.com/java/apache-poi-reading-and-writing-excel-file-in-java/